# Javascript get previous form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a nice fancy jQuery slide up form. Here's some code from the submit process:

```
    $('a.contact-submit').click(function(){
    var name = $('div.contact input.move').val();
    var email = $('div.contact input.locate').val();
    var phone = $('div.contact input.fone').val();
    var message = $('div.contact textarea.western').val();

    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

    if(reg.test(email) == false) {
    $('div.contact').hide('slow', function() {
    $('div.contact').html('<h2>Contact Us</h2><p>Sorry, there seems to be a problem with your email address. Please <a href="#" class="contact-try-again">try again</a>.</p>');
    $('div.contact').show('slow');
    });//end of slide up

    }//end of if statement for checking email.

   //SO ON, SO ON. CHECKING REST OF CLIENT INPUT....
});
```

So when a client gets an error, like the above one for invalid email, they will click 'try again'. Now I want the the slide up action to happen and then back down with the contact form. But, there must be the users previous input there.

So I have had a go of doing this:

```
$('a.contact-try-again').live('click', function(){
  $('div.contact').hide('slow', function(){
   $('div.contact').html('<h2>Contact Us</h2><form class="tab"><label for="move">Your Name:</label><input type="text" name="move"  class="move" value="'+name+'" /><br /><label for="locate">Your Email:</label><input type="text" name="locate" class="locate" value="'+email+'" /><br /><label for="locate">Your Number:</label><input type="text" name="fone" class="fone" value="'+phone+'" /><br /><label for="western">Your Message:</label><textarea name="western" class="western">'+message+'</textarea><br /><label for="contact">&nbsp;</label><a href="#contact" class="contact-submit">Send!</a><a href="#" class="prepend-1 contact-close">Cancel</a><br /></form>');
   $('div.contact').show('slow');   
 });//end of hide
});//end of contact-try-again
```

But had no luck. It slides up and doesn't slide down. I have also tried to `alert(name)`, but it doesn't pick it up.

So how can I get the values of the input and then reshow them? I'm not too experienced with Javascript, no jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some hard research I came across global variables. So here's what I did within the submit action:

```
name = $('div.contact input.move').val();
email = $('div.contact input.locate').val();
phone = $('div.contact input.fone').val();
message = $('div.contact textarea.western').val();
```

So basically I have removed the `var` at the beginning of the variable. It sets it as a global variable.

So then after that I could then use this:

```
$('a.contact-try-again').live('click', function(){
 $('div.contact').hide('slow', function(){
  $('div.contact').html('<h2>Contact Us</h2><form class="tab"><label for="move">Your Name:</label><input type="text" name="move"  class="move" value="'+name+'" /><br /><label for="locate">Your Email:</label><input type="text" name="locate" class="locate" value="'+email+'" /><br /><label for="locate">Your Number:</label><input type="text" name="fone" class="fone" value="'+phone+'" /><br /><label for="western">Your Message:</label><textarea name="western" class="western">'+message+'</textarea><br /><label for="contact">&nbsp;</label><a href="#contact" class="contact-submit">Send!</a><a href="#" class="prepend-1 contact-close">Cancel</a><br /></form>');
  $('div.contact').show('slow');   
 });//end of hide   
});
```

The reason because `.live` has been used is because it's already been modified. See more on the `.live` handler [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

So after that the submit has to be able to work, the submit action must also have the `.live` handler. Like this:

```
$('a.contact-submit').live('click', function(){
  //Code, code, code...
});
```

Hope this helps, it took me ages to figure this one out...

Answer (score 4):

you should prevent the browser from posting the form when an error occurs by adding `return false;`

```
$('a.contact-submit').click(function(){

    if(reg.test(email) == false) {
         .....//your code
         return false;
    }

});
```

or `event.preventDefault();`

```
$('a.contact-submit').click(function(event){

    if(reg.test(email) == false) {
         .....//your code
         event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

Comment: The form isn't displayed when an error has occurred. It shows an error message. That's not to do with my question.

Comment: Do keep in mind `Event.preventDefault()` does not work in IE < 9. In that case, you can do feature detection and then use `window.event.returnValue = false;` for IE browsers. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534372%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
// Retrieves value of email input.    
var email = $('input:[name=email]').attr('value');
```

Comment: var email = $('input:[name="email"]').val(); // Retrieves value of email input.

Comment: Nope, I had no luck with this either. I have tried this and to see the value of the var I have done an alert. This is the response: undefined.

Comment: And this isn't to do with my intention is it? :/